# Prove that $T$ has a minimal set and list countably many minimal sets of $T$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, ergodic-theory

> Let $X$ be a compact metric space and let $T:X \to X$ be a homeomorphism.
>
> a) When do you say that $T$ is minimal?
>
> b) When do you say that a subset $A$ of $X$ is minimal?
>
> c)Prove that $T$ has a minimal subset.
>
> d)Give an example of $X$ and $T$ such that $T$ is not minimal and which has at least countably many minimal sets. List countable many minimal sets of $T$.

Here a) $T$ is said to be minimal if $\overline{O_T(x)}=X; \forall x \in X$ where $O_T(x)$ is the orbit of $x$ in $X$.

b) A set $A$ is s.t.b minimal if it is closed under the action of $T$ and $T|_A: A \to A$ is minimal.

For c) I need proof verification.
c)I think $O_T(x)$ is itself a minimal set here. Because $T$ is a homeomorphism. So, $O_T(x)$ is closed and $T|_{O_T(x)}$ is minimal.

d) I ask for an example here. I don't know the answer.

Comment: What is the proof of $c$ you need erification of? Btw, to me it seems that $d$ shows that $T$ is not neccessarily minimal

Comment: No, @klirk see the definition of b) and then read carefully c) and d).

Comment: The persons who are downvoting towards them, let me give you the answer. The questioner is my student and I gave her the info about math stack so that if she stuck at some point then instead of mailing to professor keep a habit to post it here. It builds a good habit of solving a math problem. She posted sometime early and because it was not well organised she gets three downvotes within 2 secs.

Comment: Then she gave the details after I told her to do so and I also felt responsible that she would be feeling demotivated even if after modifying it she would be at three negative votes because the positions were the same even after 5mins of modifying and she was getting the above comments.huge amount of questions gathered here and when the question gets older, there are very few among the downvoters who really have a look at it

Comment: So I told my other students to have a look at it and support her if the question seems to be okay. When someone gets three downvotes within 2 secs there is no one to ask the reason and even I have plenty of examples where even after modifying the question the downvotes are the same because there are

Comment: a huge amount of questions gathered here and very few people look at the older questions after downvoting it. That's why I also try to edit the question and help others as I got benefitted from this site a lot. I think this solves everyone's query so if the question seems to be acceptable please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your part c) is absolutely correct.

For part d) consider $X=\{\frac 1 n| n\in \Bbb N \}\cup \{0\}$. Then consider $$T:X \to X$$ such that $T(0)=0$ and $T(\frac 1 n)=\frac 1 {n+1}$. Then $T$ is not clearly minimal as $O_T(0)=\{0\}$ but it has countable minimal subsets. You check why?